# how to write php curl request for securetrading.com payment gateway

Tags: php

I have following REQUEST TO SEND in xml. I want to send it in php. Can you help me how to write php curl function to send following xml ?

```
POST /xml/ HTTP/1.0 
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8 
Content-Length: 839 
Accept: text/xml 
Accept-Encoding: gzip 
Authorization: <BASIC AUTH CREDENTIALS HERE> 
User-Agent: <YOUR SOFTWARE VERSION HERE> 
Host: webservices.securetrading.net 
Connection: close

<requestblock version="3.67">
  <alias>webservices@securetrading.com</alias>
  <request type="AUTH">
    <operation>
      <sitereference>test_site12345</sitereference>
      <accounttypedescription>ECOM</accounttypedescription>
    </operation>
    <merchant>
      <orderreference>Example AUTH</orderreference>
      <termurl>https://www.example.com/termurl.cgi</termurl>
      <name>Test Merchant</name>
    </merchant>
    <customer>
      <ip>1.2.3.4</ip>
    </customer>
    <billing>
      <amount currencycode="GBP">2115</amount>
      <town>Bangor</town>
      <country>GB</country>
      <payment type="VISA">
        <expirydate>10/2031</expirydate>
        <pan>4111111111111111</pan>
        <securitycode>123</securitycode>
      </payment>
    </billing>
    <settlement/>
  </request>
</requestblock>
```

need help from php professional.

Comment: Sorry, but SO is _not_ a free coding service. I suggest you hire a programmer to do that work for you.

Comment: i had seen code where we can send xml directly in curl , but i could not found that url again.

Comment: Just take a look at the php curl documentation, it comes with easy examples. XML is nothing special, just a string. You just have to make a curl POST request. You certainly will be able to figure that out. Go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample you can send as xml data using curl

```
$url="http://"; // Enter url here
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "<requestblock version=\"3.67\">\r\n  <alias>webservices@securetrading.com</alias>\r\n  <request type=\"AUTH\">\r\n    <operation>\r\n      <sitereference>test_site12345</sitereference>\r\n      <accounttypedescription>ECOM</accounttypedescription>\r\n    </operation>\r\n    <merchant>\r\n      <orderreference>Example AUTH</orderreference>\r\n      <termurl>https://www.example.com/termurl.cgi</termurl>\r\n      <name>Test Merchant</name>\r\n    </merchant>\r\n    <customer>\r\n      <ip>1.2.3.4</ip>\r\n    </customer>\r\n    <billing>\r\n      <amount currencycode=\"GBP\">2115</amount>\r\n      <town>Bangor</town>\r\n      <country>GB</country>\r\n      <payment type=\"VISA\">\r\n        <expirydate>10/2031</expirydate>\r\n        <pan>4111111111111111</pan>\r\n        <securitycode>123</securitycode>\r\n      </payment>\r\n    </billing>\r\n    <settlement/>\r\n  </request>\r\n</requestblock>",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "accept-encoding: application/gzip",        
        "content-type: text/xml"
    ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was just need a hint of code. Now i will be able to resolve issue.